# Doctrine in Symfony : is nullable impossible in ternary relationship for the key parts

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

In my schema i have a ternary relationship between User, Institution and Session entities.

I could understand a "regular" table key (simple Id) couldn't be null  but i would like to have (userId, institutionId, NULL) or (NULL, institutionId, sessionId), or even (NULL, NULL, sessionId)...
Is it not possible with a ternary relationship or did i miss some annotation markings ?

I would not like to have to "artificially" change this ternary into a regular entity with a primary id key, and those 3 element as foreign keys.
Thank you for any help.
I also adjusted the setter to accept the null values for those elements.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="institutioncontactsessionorganization")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyBundle\Repository\InstitutionContactSessionOrganizationRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"icsoInstitution", "icsoSession", "icsoUser"},
 *     errorPath="departmentName",
 *     message="this association already exists"
 * )
 */
class InstitutionContactSessionOrganization
{
  /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MyBundle\Entity\Institution", inversedBy="icsos")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="institutionId", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
   */
  private $icsoInstitution;

  /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MyBundle\Entity\Session", inversedBy="icsos")
   * @ORM\JoinColumns({
   *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="sessionId", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
   * })
   */
  private $icsoSession;

  /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MyBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="icsos")
   * @ORM\JoinColumns({
   *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="userId", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
   * })
   */
  private $icsoUser;
...
}
```

When i create table with the command the nullable attribute is not taken into account

```
CREATE TABLE institutioncontactsessionorganization (departmentName VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, phone VARCHAR(16) DEFAULT NULL, institutionId INT NOT NULL, sessionId INT NOT NULL, userId INT NOT NULL, INDEX IDX_43EDEF2F76065B2 (institutionId), INDEX IDX_43EDEF23950B5F6 (sessionId), INDEX IDX_43EDEF264B64DCC (userId), PRIMARY KEY(institutionId, sessionId, userId)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE institutioncontactsessionorganization ADD CONSTRAINT FK_43EDEF2F76065B2 FOREIGN KEY (institutionId) REFERENCES institution (id);
ALTER TABLE institutioncontactsessionorganization ADD CONSTRAINT FK_43EDEF23950B5F6 FOREIGN KEY (sessionId) REFERENCES session (id);
ALTER TABLE institutioncontactsessionorganization ADD CONSTRAINT FK_43EDEF264B64DCC FOREIGN KEY (userId) REFERENCES user (id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just post it on [Doctrine github](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/6647#issuecomment-324831341) and it appears you can't have any part of a primary key (so also a composite key) to be null.